selectorprimaryfocus in ComboBox
I am trying to set focus to a comboBox which is present inside a Tearsheet when the tearsheet is opened. but it doesnt work.
import { ComboBox } from "@carbon/react";
import { Tearsheet } from "@carbon/ibm-products";

<ComboBox id="selectRecordType" />

<Tearsheet open={this.props.isOpen} selectorPrimaryFocus = "#selectRecordType"/>

I want the focus to be moved to the combobox, but the focus still stays outside the tearsheet which is the home page. This doesnt happen if I have any simple input inside the tearsheet. I can move the focus to the input. The problem is only with Combobox

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
